# Python re match at specific point in string

Tags: python, regex

If I have a given string `s` in Python, is it possible to easily check if a regex matches the string starting at a specific position `i` in the string?

I would rather not slice the entire string from `i` to the end as it doesn't seem very scalable (ruling out `re.match` I think).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) doesn't support this directly. However, if you pre-compile your regular expression (often a good idea anyway) with [`re.compile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile), then the [`RegexObject`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject)'s similar method, [`match`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.match)  (and [`search`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.search)) both take an optional *pos* parameter:

> The optional second parameter *pos* gives an index in the string where the search is to start; it defaults to `0`. This is not completely equivalent to slicing the string; the `'^'` pattern character matches at the real beginning of the string and at positions just after a newline, but not necessarily at the index where the search is to start.

Example:

```
import re
s = 'this is a test 4242 did you get it'
pat = re.compile('[a-zA-Z]+ ([0-9]+)')
print pat.match(s, 10).group(0)
```

Output:

```
'test 4242'
```

Comment: I feel very confused when I see that the match object has the property `pos`, because the match method of `re` does not have this parameter. It wasn't until I saw the answer that I suddenly realized that this method only exists on compiled regex objects.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although `re.match` does not support this, the new [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module (intended to replace the `re` module) has a treasure trove of new features, including `pos` and `endpos` arguments for `search`, `match`, `sub`, and `subn`. Although not official yet, the [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module can be pip installed and works for Python versions 2.5 through 3.4. Here's an example:

```
>>> import regex

>>> regex.match(r'\d+', 'abc123def')

>>> regex.match(r'\d+', 'abc123def', pos=3)
<regex.Match object; span=(3, 6), match='123'>

>>> regex.match(r'\d+', 'abc123def', pos=3, endpos=5)
<regex.Match object; span=(3, 5), match='12'>
```